# Session token isn't storing and isn't viewable from browser

Tags: node.js, express-session

I'm trying to setup a session storage of a userID for an app im working on and I cannot for the life of me get express-session to work.

I've checked out a ton of stack overflow posts, tutorials, and other websites and followed all of the instructions there to no avail. The cookie doesn't even appear in the browser. I've tried changing the order of the .use as well and no other location worked.

Here's the code

```
const session = require('express-session');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const App = require('./app');

var app = new App();
const server = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3030;

server.use(cors());
server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, buildPath)));

server.use(cookieParser());

server.use(session({
  key: 'user_sid',
  secret: 'somerandonstuffs',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 10000,
    secure: false,
    ttpOnly: false
  }
}));

server.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.cookies);
  console.log(req.session);
  if (req.cookies.user_sid && !req.session.user) {
    res.clearCookie('user_sid');
  }
  next();
});

server.get('/api/userRole', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const role = await app.userRole(req.query.userID, req.query.email);
    res.send({ role });
    req.session.user = req.query.userID; //assign
  }
  catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});

server.get('/api/music', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.session.user) //returns undefined
    const uid = req.query.user;
    app.checkAuth(uid, app.constants.roles.member);
    const music = await app.music(req.query.status);
    res.send(music);
  }
  catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

And here is the result from the console logs

```
{}
Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2019-07-19T22:01:58.342Z,
     originalMaxAge: 10000,
     httpOnly: false,
     secure: false } }
{}
Session {
  cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2019-07-19T22:01:58.387Z,
     originalMaxAge: 10000,
     httpOnly: false,
     secure: false } }
undefined
```

All I can seem to get as a response is undefined. Any idea what might be going wrong? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Couple things: you aren't supposed to use `cookie-parser` with `express-session`.  There can be conflicts with the cookie secret across the 2 middleware.

You could also consider `cookie-session`, which will be much simpler to use conceptually

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I removed cookie parser and tried cookie-session but still ran into the same issue where the broswer never recognized a cookie being set. Im gonna give it another shot but it was still the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up a storage option for `express-session.` The easiest one to set up is [session-file-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/session-file-store), but I'd recommend using something like [connect-redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-redis) for a production environment.

You then pass the session storage instance to the `express-session` options like this:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);

var fileStoreOptions = {};

app.use(session({
   store: new FileStore(fileStoreOptions),
   secret: 'keyboard cat'
}));
```